# volley response time

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have some question about volley

- How can i get connection response time with volley library?
- Have a solution for it?
- can i use timer for getting the response time?how?
- And also have a method for execute before connection in volley ?

my code like this:

```
final String URL = "http://domain.com/conn.php";
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) 
    {
        startActivity(new intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
    {
        if(RRequestErrorHelper.getMessage(error) == null || RRequestErrorHelper.getMessage(error).isEmpty())
        {
        }
        zLog.error(RRequestErrorHelper.getMessage(error));
    }
});

zRequestHelper.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req,"TAG");
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess this would work out fine. i actually didn't tried it but they are providing it as log output. i saw that GOOGLE I/O session for volley he just mentioned it. below is the screenshot from that session

[image]

in that session he mentioned that it will generate log entries in verbose and there is time for each operation from adding request into queue to post the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need `VolleyLog`

- [Refer link 1](https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/5980715)
- [Refer link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23654407/2820534)
- [Refer link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21425274/2820534)

add `VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;` in code.

from adb, try this :

- If you've many devices - `adb -s [deviceId] shell setprop
  log.tag.Volley VERBOSE`
- If you've 1 device - `adb [deviceId] shell setprop log.tag.Volley
  VERBOSE`
- If you've testing in emulator - `adb emulator-5555 shell setprop
  log.tag.Volley VERBOSE`